# ng-show on ionic button

Tags: angularjs, button, ionic-framework, ng-show

I want to hide thebutton at the begin until I have presses another buttons to make them appear...
My codes are as followed:

The button Controller + javascript:

```
<div ng-controller="PrintTicket">
              <button class="button button-dark" id="btn-printTicket" ng-click="isPrinted()">Print Ticket</button><br></div>


myIonic.controller('PrintTicket',function($scope){
var init_state = false;
 $scope.isPrinted = init_state;
$scope.PrintTicket = function(){
$scope.isPrinted = !init_state;
return $scope.isPrinted;
} });
```

The button to display after click:

```
<div ng-controller="PrintTicket" ng-show="isPrinted">
                <button class="button button-dark" id="ticket1_dark"><b>1234</b></button></div>
```

May you please kindly give me some advices please. Thank you for your time.

[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BggLopWPmvn81Kh72BaX?p=preview)

Comment: There is no `isPrinted()` function definition in that.

Answer (score 1):

For printing ticket you should call `PrintTicket` function instead of `isPrinted` which will then set `isSelected` flag.

```
ng-click="PrintTicket()"
```

You shouldn't be defining `ng-controller="PrintTicket"` twice which will instantiate controller function again.  You should have both divs wrap inside single controller called `PrintTicket`

[**Plunkr Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4WRVwYYred7ctPwR1hJh?p=preview)

---

After a discussion it seems like you wanted to share a data amongest two controller, so for that reason you could service to sharing data between two controller. So you can set service variable in one controller and access that value from service inside another controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have already made a change on it,,, but it doesnt work :(

Comment: @Sammi could you reproduce in the plunkr?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/BggLopWPmvn81Kh72BaX?p=preview
Hi, here is the link, thank you for your time

Comment: @Sammi check attached demo

Comment: Thank you for your demo. I have followed your code and also changed the function name of PrintTicket, but the "1234" button still did not appear as your demo.... and I have checked the console that the value of "$scope.isPrinted" is true but it didn't show....

Comment: You have to remove one ng-controller & wrap button element to show/hide inside ng-controller div..

Comment: but they will be display in different list divider in ion-list... I cannot put them into the same div... is there any other method to deal with it if they must be in separated div??

Comment: So you consider to create a service to share isPrinted value amongst two controller

Comment: oh i see.. let me try to do so. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Will try to create plunkr for you

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!!! I am really new to ionic so it has been a struggling period for me....

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div ng-controller="PrintTicket">
          <button class="button button-dark" id="btn-printTicket"
  ng-click="isPrinted()">Print Ticket</button><br></div>


 <div ng-controller="PrintTicket" ng-show="showPrintButton">
   <button class="button button-dark" id="ticket1_dark"><b>1234</b></button></div>





myIonic.controller('PrintTicket',function(`enter code here`$scope){
var init_state = false;

$scope.showPrintButton = false;
$scope.isPrinted=function(){    //$scope.isPrinted is a function
$scope.showPrintButton = true;
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have implemented your code but it still doesn't work... the second button is hided but it never shows up even I have clicked the first button

Comment: I have checked with the console, seems I have ran that line of code ($scope.showPrintButton = true), but the button still did not show up

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kGTI4ATNdxPD2d2UWNAn?p=preview   - try this plunker

Comment: Thank you for your demo.. but it does not work for me, even I have put them into the same div wrapper by PrintTicket controller

Comment: Check whether you have included angualrjs and jquery script files and your controller file in index.html

Comment: Also check whether u have included this in your html - <html ng-app="starter">

Comment: I have included them all, then I guess actually I need to share the values between two controllers as I need to put the two buttons in separated divs so such its controller.... Anyway, thank you so much for your help!